# Conditional forwarders in Azure Vnet not working

Tags: azure, dns

This the current setup:

**Azure vnet:**

- 10.10.10.1 = DC1
- 10.3.1.1 = VM1
- 10.3.1.2 = VM1

**Private Cloud:**

- 192.168.0.2 = DC2
- 192.168.0.114 = VM3 aka `VM3.private.domain.com`

**DC1** has a DNS Conditional forwarder set up for zone `private.domain.com` to **DC2**

On all Azure VM's, the `nslookup` only works when I specify the IP of **DC2**,
when just doing `nslookup vm3.private.domain.com`, it renders:

```
Address:  10.10.10.1

*** UnKnown can't find vm3.private.domain.com: Non-existent domain
```

Specifying the IP of `DC2` works

```
nslookup vm3.private.domain.com 192.168.0.2
Server:  UnKnown
Address:  192.168.0.2

Name:    vm3.private.domain.com
Address:  192.168.0.114
```

For some reason, on **VM1**, a `ping vm3.private.domain.com` works fine ??? (any http calls too)

But on **VM2** I get:

```
ping vm3.private.domain.com
Ping request could not find host vm3.private.domain.com. Please check the name and try again.
```

I have no clue where to start looking why the two VM's are displaying different behaviours.
They both share the same Azure network security group.

*Edit:
A S2S VPN is in place between the networks, pinging on IP works both ways.

Comment: Is the IP address `10.3.1.1` and `10.3.1.2` a real IP address for VMs in the same virtual network? `addresses 10.0.0.0-10.0.0.3 and 10.0.255.255 cannot be assigned to resources.` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-ip-addresses-overview-arm#allocation-method-1

Comment: 10.3.1.1 and 10.3.1.2 are real ip addresses. Those two VM's are in the same Azure VNET

Comment: If you use nslookup on both vm1 and vm2, the result is the same?

Comment: the nslookups on both machines vm1 and vm2 is the same.

Comment: Try to Flush DNS resolver cache : `ipconfig /flushdns`, then ping again? or Reset WINSOCK entries to installation defaults :`netsh winsock reset catalog`
Reset TCP/IP stack to installation defaults : `netsh int ip reset reset.log`

Comment: tried all that, no good :(

Comment: Have you checked the [`hosts` file](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/hosts-file-in-windows) in the location “C:/Windows/System32/drivers/etc/” on both VMs? What's the result when you access www.google.com in the web browser?

Comment: Any update? Can you [specify the DNS server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-networks-name-resolution-for-vms-and-role-instances#specify-dns-servers) of the Azure VNet to the DNS server address 10.10.10.1? Both DC1 and DC2 are DNS servers?

Comment: No still not resolved :(

Comment: both hosts files are the same (default), both have access to the internet

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that "Private Cloud" is across a Virtual Network Gateway (VNG) possibly using a IPsec/VPN, and assuming DCx are AD-integrated DNS:
It's likely that your ForwarderTimeout on DC1 is too short for that connection topology.  Check with:

```
Get-DNSServerForwarder -ComputerName DC1
```

and

```
Get-DNSServerZone -ComputerName DC1 -Name private.domain.com | Fl
```

Set values that are what you expect your network to handle, considering the time IPsec tunnel connection takes to be established for your CPE.

Secondarily, it's likely that the DNS cache should be adjusted for the network.  Check with :

```
Get-DNSServerCache -ComputerName DC1 | Fl
```

Consider how MaxNegativeTTL should be set when DNS returns a negative query/forward.  You may want to clear those out more frequently than the 00:15:00 default.